# How to show passcode screen in iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, passcode

I have developed some code to using **touch id** and it's works correctly.
But when using wrong finger show me error and not authorize like this:

[image]

So in this situation I want to when tap on **Enter Password** , show me passcode screen to type my iPhone passcode(I don't know exist any api for this). 
And how to handle **Enter Password** button after tapping(Delegate or ...).

Thank you.

Comment: I not think you can change the behaviour of the dialog, since this would be a big security issue. The API will show the passcode/password screen.

Comment: which api handle Enter Passcode or Show it in swift? @rckoenes

Comment: It's all in the [LocalAuthentication Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication).

Comment: @rckoenes I saw this. it's just handle Touch ID not passcode.

Comment: Not it does not, when you pass [deviceOwnerAuthentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/1514164-deviceownerauthentication) it will use the pass-word/code option.

Comment: @rckoenes https://paste.laravel.io/2cf68864-5c64-4553-bec3-4286cc311f20  is this wrong?

Comment: You are using `deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics`  which is touch/face-id use `deviceOwnerAuthentication` to only password/passcode

Comment: Not working, no difference @rckoenes

Comment: You cannot present the fallback to passcode in the event of a failed biometric when using local authentication. You can require biometric only when you are retrieving an item from the keychain that has `kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny` but not `kSecAccessControlApplicationPassword` in its access control flags